# how can we play youtube videos in dailymotion player new beta version

Tags: javascript, dailymotion-api

So far this is what I have:

adding player js

```
<script src="http://api.dmcdn.net/all.js"></script>

<script>
    DM.init({
          apiKey: 'my app key',
          status: true, // check login status
          cookie: true // enable cookies to allow the server to   access the session
    });


    // Append a div in the DOM, you may use a real <div> tag
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(div);


    var videos = 'xdn8vw'; // this is the video id from dailymotions site now i want to play the any youtube video
    var player = DM.player(div, {video: videos });


</script>
```

so i need the player to play this video 'https://youtu.be/hXI8RQYC36Q?list=PLFgquLnL59akA2PflFpeQG9L01VFg90wS'

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The dailymotion player can only read dailymotion videos just as the youtube player only allows you to play youtube videos.