# is there any way play youtube videos in dailymotion player new beta version

Tags: javascript, php, dailymotion-api

So far this is what I have:
so i need the player to play this video 'https://youtu.be/hXI8RQYC36Q?list=PLFgquLnL59akA2PflFpeQG9L01VFg90wS'

```
  adding player js
 <script src="http://api.dmcdn.net/all.js"></script>

    <script>
        DM.init({
          apiKey: 'my app key',
          status: true, // check login status
          cookie: true // enable cookies to allow the server to   access the session
    });


    // Append a div in the DOM, you may use a real <div> tag
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(div);


    var videos = 'xdn8vw'; // this is the video id from dailymotions site now i want to play the any youtube video
    var player = DM.player(div, {video: videos });


</script>
```

any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know what video formats Dailymotion player supports. Then you have to download this YouTube video before you can play it back.

Comment: Not sure if my edit has changed what you meant; if not, feel free to revert it.

Answer (score 0):

already answered at [how can we play youtube videos in dailymotion player new beta version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433079/how-can-we-play-youtube-videos-in-dailymotion-player-new-beta-version)

The Dailymotion player can only read videos hosted on Dailymotion just as the Youtube player only allows you to play Youtube videos.